# Selecting a group of words separated with space with regex

Tags: regex

I have following example of data in which I need to extract the first Unique number and then the name which falls between unique number and some float value preceding it.

**H1765 CONTI CANBERRA 13.4 278.8 CISC TSI 28/23:00 Sa 28/13:00    28/15 00/15  1595 1700**

I wrote following regex to select `H1725` in first group and the name `CONTI CANBERRA` in second group.

```
(H\d+)\s+(\w+\s)*.*\d+
```

Problem is that it doesn't select the name in second group. The name can contain any number of words separated by a space. We know the name has ended when there a float value comes after it. Please let me know how can I get both values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(H\d+)\s+([\w\s]*?)\s*\d+\.\d
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/shVD5E/1/). Prepend with `\b` word boundary if `H` is the first letter in the word. Here is [its scheme](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(H%5Cd%2B)%5Cs%2B(%5B%5Cw%5Cs%5D*%3F)%5Cs*%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd):

[image]

**Details**

- `(H\d+)` - Group 1: `H` and 1+ digits
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `([\w\s]*?)` - Group 2: 0+ word or whitespace chars
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\d+\.\d` - 1+ digits, `.` and a digit

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This captures the first as well as the second group:

```
(H\d+)\s+([A-Za-z\s]+)(?=\s+\d+\.\d)
```

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/n8rIVl/3)

**Explanation**

- **`(H\d+)\s+`:** match H followed by 1+ digits, capture them, then match 1+ spaces
- **`([A-Za-z\s]+)`:** match 1+ `A-Za-z` and `\s`
- **`(?=\s+\d+\.\d)`**: then a positive lookahead to match spaces followed by digits followed by a `.` again followed by a digit.